# Implement Did you mean this? in Solr for e-commerce site

Tags: solr

For an e-commerce website where Search is using a Solr...we are having a product with processor, professor, and prophecy in Solr index.

We are making a query for following term into search "prophesor". And we have no document that exactly match with this query.

So, we need to display a result like Google... where we will show that..

> No matching results for "prophesor".
>
> Showing results for "prophesy" instead. Did you mean - procesor or professor ?

We are trying with Solr Fuzzy Query as described into Solr Wiki, but that doesn't does this... instead it includes a results that are similar to the search terms.

For above to work... we understand following..
1. to make a default search into Solr for given term..
2. if no result is found, we will need to do another search into Solr for closely matching search terms and
3. offer result for the first closest match term on a page and a next closest match terms link for search results page.

However, we have no clue on how to implement this? We have been trying with Fuzzy search but that doesn't seem to fit this kind of requirement. What exactly we need to do?

Specifically how to find the closely matching terms in case no results is found for a given term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably need to check for [Solr spell check component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent) which will provide you with Did you mean kind of suggestions.
It supports spell suggestion, collation, also the Lucene Spell checkers sort suggestions first by the score from the string distance calculation and second by the frequency (if available) of the suggestion in the index

However, Solr by itself won't query for the spell terms.
That needs to be handled at the Client side, where you check for 0 results and pick up the first result to query to Solr.
You can show the other results as suggestions.
Also, you can use Index based spell which will ensure you have the results for the suggested terms.

Comment: @Jayendra... I was just thinking that you must be helping me again on this issue as well.... haaha... I am looking into Spell Check component now. Does it require to make different query into Solr for Spell Check, or it does it automatically if no result is found?

Comment: the spell suggestion would be included within the same query. However for the results you would need to fire an extra query from the client side.

Comment: Okay, that make sense.. I'm now trying this.. will update once I'm done. Thank you for your super fast response.

Comment: This works as you suggested.. but now we have another issue - may be related to the solr config for spellcheck.. we're trying to configure it correctly.. however for this question... your suggestion is worth, and helped us achieve the results we needed. Thank you

Comment: @Jayendra I also have problem with Spell Check. Can you please view this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147969/wrong-spell-check-suggestions-by-solr Thanks In Advance.