# Wrong spell-check suggestions by Solr

Tags: solr, full-text-search, solr4

Working on Spell Suggest with Solr 4.1.

We configured it correctly and Solr offers term as well as collate suggestions. However, we noticed that many times the suggested word / collate doesn't have any results if we search it again.

For example, we searched for term "**confort**" and got no results, with two suggestions "**comfort**" and "**convert**". The first term contains the result.. however the second term doesn't bring any result, and instead suggested two more terms, so term "convert" offers no result with following suggestions - "**connect**" and "**content**". Here also, we found that "**connect**" is having few results but "**content**" doesn't have any and offered following suggestions.. i.e. "**connect**" and "**continent**". Here also we found that "**continent**" doesn't have any results and it suggested "**connect**".

The same happens for many search terms and even collate. We're clueless what is causing this? Can we turn off such suggestions which doesn't carry any result?

My Solr Config

```
<requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">Name</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>       
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>       
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>  
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>         
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>

<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
<str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text</str>
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">default</str>
  <str name="field">Name</str>
  <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
  <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
  <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
  <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
  <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
  <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
  <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
  <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
</lst>

<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
  <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>      
  <str name="field">Name</str>
  <str name="combineWords">true</str>
  <str name="breakWords">false</str>
  <int name="maxChanges">10</int>     
</lst>
</searchComponent>
```

My Schema :

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>   
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="Name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"  required="false" />
```

My Query : `http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/spell?q=confort&spellcheck=true&Collate=true&spellcheck.extendedResults=true`

Result :

```
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">16</int>
  </lst>
  <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
  <lst name="spellcheck">
    <lst name="suggestions">
      <lst name="confort">
        <int name="numFound">2</int>
        <int name="startOffset">0</int>
        <int name="endOffset">7</int>
        <int name="origFreq">0</int>
        <arr name="suggestion">
          <lst>
            <str name="word">comfort</str>
            <int name="freq">6</int>
          </lst>
          <lst>
            <str name="word">convert</str>
            <int name="freq">2</int>
          </lst>
        </arr>
      </lst>
      <bool name="correctlySpelled">false</bool>
    </lst></lst>
  </response>
```

Comment: Is your suggester configured to get suggest from the index of a field or from the dictionary?

Comment: @Junaid I have updated question with config details. Please have a look. Moreover we are getting suggestion from Index.

Comment: I have a small confusion. You say when you search for confort, Solr returns 0 results but suggests comfort and convert. Now comfort gives you results but convert does not and instead gives you connect and content as suggestions. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Junaid Yes you're correct.

Comment: Does convert, content and continent have any mention in the synonyms.txt? If yes then what are they.

Comment: @Junaid No our synonyms.txt file is empty. It doesn't contains anythings.

Comment: If the synonyms file is empty then why do you use it in the anaylzer. Also, Can you help me with the search query?

Comment: @Junaid Synonyms file is empty but we need to configure after deploying so we need it there. And please review my question I have updated it with my query and its xml result.

Comment: Krutal - Can you show me how does your search query looks like for the word convert?

Comment: @Junaid My Query for convert is : localhost:8983/solr/mycore/select?q=Name:Convert

Comment: It is really strange. The only thing that seems a little out of place is your empty synonym.txt file. BUT i do not think that is the problem.

Comment: @Junaid Synonyms.txt file is our future requirement so we have put there. And you are right it should not be problem. So I have provided all info in my question, now do you have any idea why this is happening? Please help me.

Comment: Any update here, I'm having same issues..

Comment: @Junaid    I'm also have similar problem but little bit different in my case Spell corrections & Suggestions working fine.... Please take a look at this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196793/how-get-suggestions-from-solr-server-in-a-php-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the terms you search on and the spell check enabled on the same ? do they go under the same analysis ?
One reason can be the fields are different and hence the suggestions on field provided do not exist in the fields that are being searched for.
Also, it can be the fields are analysed differently and hence the spell suggestion and the search does not match.

Answer (score 0):

You said in the comment, you are getting suggestion from index, but your configuration was not.

```
<str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
```

change the above to this

```
<str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str>
```

Comment: <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str> is not working. It throws error - java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: I am also getting error saying "java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.String"...Please elaborate your answer....