# Offer related searches using Solr 4

Tags: search, solr

How to display a Related Searches suggestions on a Search Result page..

So for example, if I'm searching for SSL, I want to suggest.. SSL Certificates, SSL Seal, Secure Site using SSL, Premium SSL Certificate as a suggestions...

Is this something which can be developed using Solr? As we're performing searches using Solr 4.0.

Comment: If you are searching for SSL, shouldn't suggestions you listed simply be a match? Word "SSL" is in all of them. Can you explain in a bit more details what you want to achieve?

Comment: Take a look at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester. It might inspire you. But you won't have an out of the box complete solution.

Comment: Did you check this https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr does not provide Out of the Box suggestions for previous searches.
SO if you want to suggest related searches with Solr, you have to index the previous searches and then provide them as Auto suggestion.
You can do it as the search is performed or mine the query logs for the same.
The approach can be using normal search as I see from you example where you are trying to look only for SSL in the content of the previous search performed.

Comment: Hey Jayendra... thank you for this answer. Probably this needs to be implemented out side solr in this case. Thanks

Comment: Can you also look into this issue.. I'm also facing same issue... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147969/wrong-spell-check-suggestions-by-solr Or should I create new question instead of follow this one?