# Could it possible to get related documents in Solr search query?

Tags: solr

I use the following query string to get a document indexed in Solr:

`http://localhost:8080/solr/newsarchive/select/?q=ID:bbc-55950440dc8e5f1a550bd736214a1e7e&sort=Date%20desc&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&wt=json`

Which returns the specified document of ID `bbc-55950440dc8e5f1a550bd736214a1e7e`.

My question is: Is there any way to make this query returns a number of related documents IDs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Offer related searches using Solr 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358186/offer-related-searches-using-solr-4)

Comment: Have you looked at the [More Like This](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis) component?

Comment: I would also look up the [More Like This component in the Solr Reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/MoreLikeThis). This is usually more pleasant to read.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this in Solr, it's called More Like This: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis

You pass Solr a query and the More Like This handler will return similar documents for each document the query you passed in would return. It determines similarity by looking at the terms in fields that you select and running a Lucene query using those terms.

The fields you select need at a minimum to be stored, preferably they should be set up to store term vectors:

```
<field name="cat" ... termVectors="true" />
```

An example query (taken from the documentation):

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=apache&mlt=true&mlt.fl=manu,cat
```

In this case you are querying the index for the word "apache" and requesting a more like this result set (mlt=true). You are asking Solr to base the similar on the fields manu and cat. Solr will then look at the terms in those fields and perform a search on those fields using those terms to locate similar documents.

A few more articles/examples:

http://blog.brattland.no/node/18

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/MoreLikeThis