# Stop incorrect terms from indexing in data-import handler in Apache SOLR

Tags: apache, solr, dataimporthandler

I have a table in mysql named "searchterms" which include data of searches terms performed by the users.

I'm indexing these search terms in solr and using suggest component for getting suggestions for searches based on other users.(That is popular searches among communities)

I have database that is old and I have a lot old incorrect/misspelled searches.

What I exactly want to do is stop indexing those incorrect/misspelled terms and index only correctly spelled terms.

I'm using data-import handler connected with mysql to index old data.

Any solution for this problem.

Comment: What is an "incorrect term"? You'll have to have a way of determining either what are the only words that should be indexed, or what are the words that should be excluded.

Comment: incorrect term mean spelling mistakes. Like "prioty initiatives" which is correctly as "priority initiatives".

That field only search phrases done via users in the portal, so user can search incorrect search words or phrases as well, I don't wanna index those.

Comment: You'll have to have some way to determine what a misspelled word is. Do you have a wordlist or dictionary that you can use? There is nothing inherent in Solr for saying "this is correctly spelled" - as that's usually determined by the term counts for similar fields.

Comment: Yes I have a core solely related to documents and those search terms are used to search those documents/contents. 

I can do it like request solr to get data from that other core against each search term and see if I get spell suggestions or not and then index based on it.

But this is a hectic approach.

Comment: If you do have a proper word list for the terms you want to keep (i.e. either exported once from your other core, or by using a predefined dictionary from aspell or a similar resource), you can use the [Keep Word Filter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-KeepWordFilter) to remove any terms that doesn't match the spelling given in your wordlist.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this out - https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent.

There are a few cavaets to it, check out - [Wrong spell-check suggestions by Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147969/wrong-spell-check-suggestions-by-solr)

Comment: I have already used this component for implementing Did You mean ? feature.

The fact is I have search terms searched by portal users indexed into SOLR and I get suggestions using suggest component based on these search terms.

Now those incorrect search terms also get returned via Suggest Component.

Comment: Also I don't want to get suggestions from content these are just popular search terms in the portal among users.

Comment: The question description was not clear in whether you already using this component or simply looking for ways to implement this. 

You may also want to update the question with the configs. That would help understand it better.

Comment: I have a table in mysql name "searchterms" which include data of searches terms performed by the users.

I'm indexing these search terms in solr and using suggest component for getting suggestions for searches based on other users.

Now I have database that is old and I have a lot old incorrect/misspelled searches.

What I exactly want to do is stop indexing those incorrect/misspelled  terms.

I'm using data-import handler connected with mysql to index old data.

Comment: I have updated the question description. I hope it makes sense now.